# python app engine backend works in SDK but not when deployed

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a test backend defined like this in my backends.yaml

```
backends: 
- name: mailer 
  class: B1
  instances: 1 
  start: loaders/mail_backend.py
```

my mail_backend.py script looks like this:

```
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.api import logservice
import logging

logservice.AUTOFLUSH_ENABLED = False
logging.error("Backend started!")
logservice.flush()

mail.send_mail(sender="email@email.com", to="email@email.com", subject="Testing Backend", body="Testing if backend is running")

logging.error("Backend finished running!")
logservice.flush()
```

When I run this locally in the SDK  (v 1.7.1 on Mac OS X) it works fine (as do all my other backends) but when I deploy and update the backends nothing happens.   The backend is showing that it's running and has a Stop button showing but nothing shows up in the logs.

How can I debug what is going on here?  I can't seem to tell if the backend is even getting called.   Just for kicks I also rewrote my backend to behave like a request handler and when I tried running it that way and hit the URL I designated to run it, I got an error page asking to report the problem to the App Engine team if it kept occurring. I haven't done that yet as I really don't want to run it as a request handler since my backends only need to run one time to load data into the datastore.

Thanks for any help

Comment: For a one-off operation to load data into the datastore I did exactly what you mention - attached it's trigger to a handler and called it via  that handler. So it does work fine like that if you can fix that error.

Comment: Thanks Paul. And I know it works as well as I did a dry run on a test application in App engine and loaded 100K records just fine.  For some reason though it doesn't work on my real production application and I can't figure out why it doesn't work.   I just want to know what the backend service is running into (error wise if that's what the problem is) so I can debug this.

Comment: Just a few more comments - I refactored to model the counter.py example from Google IO 2011 regarding backends and again it works in the SDK but not when deployed.

Comment: I've not used it, but the backend seems to support some logging interface that might be of use? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#Fetching_Request_Logs_and_Application_Logs

Comment: Well if you look at my code above I'm using the log service to flush the logs - they're not showing up anywhere.  There's also no logs showing that _ah/start was called against my backends either which is why I'm stuck.

Comment: duh. Of course you are. Long day....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well unfortunately this isn't ideal as an answer but on a hunch I decided to create a new App Engine application and push my code to it.

I did that just now and now my backends work fine (no code changes BTW).

Unfortunately I lost my app engine name in the process which is kind of a drag.  I wish there was a way to keep an application name inside the same account if you deleted one.